# IOS prevent zoom on text input

Tags: javascript, ios, zooming

How do you prevent zoom on a text input in IOS?  I know this has been asked before, and the conventional wisdom has been to have at least 16px font on the input.

However, this does not seem to be working with modern ios devices (recent iphones), though it does seem to work on an older ipad.

Any current solutions?  I am preferably looking for a css, or pure javascript solution.

I am aware that we could disable zoom altogether for the page, but that is not a desirable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to specify all inputs and also added focus property like this:

```
@media #{$small-and-down} {
  // styles for small screens and down
  input[type="color"],
  input[type="date"],
  input[type="datetime"],
  input[type="datetime-local"],
  input[type="email"],
  input[type="month"],
  input[type="number"],
  input[type="password"],
  input[type="search"],
  input[type="tel"],
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="time"],
  input[type="url"],
  input[type="week"],
  select:focus,
  textarea {
   font-size: 16px !important;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  select:focus,
  textarea:focus,
  input:focus {
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
}
```